# hibernate with jpa doesn't stop

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

I am beginning with hibernate and JPA and I have been following several tutorials on JPA with eclipse link on Netbeans, however, while still working on Netbeans I downloaded the hibernate-release-5.2.7.Final.zip manually from Hibernate web page and as stated here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#_the_hibernate_modules_artifacts
I added the lib/required directory and the lib/jpa-metamodel-generator/ to my java application and mysql conector jar, after that, I created my persistence.xml as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Aplication" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="verde"/>


      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

then I created a sample Entity Prueba:

```
package Model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table
public class Prueba implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String nombre;



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Prueba)) {
            return false;
        }
        Prueba other = (Prueba) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model.Prueba[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

and I added a JPA ControllerClass from Entity through NetBeans wizard:

```
 package Model;

import Model.exceptions.NonexistentEntityException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

/**
 *
 * @author Spencer
 */
public class PruebaJpaController implements Serializable {

    public PruebaJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(Prueba prueba) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(prueba);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void edit(Prueba prueba) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            prueba = em.merge(prueba);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
                Long id = prueba.getId();
                if (findPrueba(id) == null) {
                    throw new NonexistentEntityException("The prueba with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy(Long id) throws NonexistentEntityException {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Prueba prueba;
            try {
                prueba = em.getReference(Prueba.class, id);
                prueba.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The prueba with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
            }
            em.remove(prueba);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Prueba> findPruebaEntities() {
        return findPruebaEntities(true, -1, -1);
    }

    public List<Prueba> findPruebaEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        return findPruebaEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
    }

    private List<Prueba> findPruebaEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(Prueba.class));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all) {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public Prueba findPrueba(Long id) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            return em.find(Prueba.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public int getPruebaCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            Root<Prueba> rt = cq.from(Prueba.class);
            cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Next, to that I created a quick Dao for testing Hibernate:

```
package Model;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class PruebaDao {
    private static EntityManagerFactory em;
    private static PruebaJpaController pjpa;

    public PruebaDao(){
        em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Aplication");
        pjpa = new PruebaJpaController(em);
    }

    public void addPrueba(Prueba pb){
        pjpa.create(pb);
    }

}
```

and after creating my main class:

```
    package javaapplication7;

import Model.Prueba;
import Model.PruebaDao;

/**
 *
 * @author Spencer
 */
public class JavaApplication7 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prueba pb = new Prueba();
        PruebaDao pbdao = new PruebaDao();

        pb.setNombre("numerouno");

        pbdao.addPrueba(pb);

    }

}
```

Everything works fine the object is added to MySQL but the app doesn't close on finish here is the log:

```
    feb 13, 2017 4:51:55 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: Aplication
    ...]
feb 13, 2017 4:51:56 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.7.Final}
feb 13, 2017 4:51:56 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
feb 13, 2017 4:51:57 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
feb 13, 2017 4:51:57 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
feb 13, 2017 4:51:57 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
feb 13, 2017 4:51:57 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
feb 13, 2017 4:51:57 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
feb 13, 2017 4:51:58 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
feb 13, 2017 4:52:02 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
feb 13, 2017 4:52:06 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@52a3ff] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
```

The thing is that I would usually do the same through eclipse link and everything would work fine.

Here my dependencies[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gabwR.jpg)

Comment: Take a thread dump and find which thread is still alive. Considering that it is most likely some library's thread it will have a meaningful name.

Comment: I am very new into this but the following threads had a state of runnable: RMI TCP Connection(3) 192.168.1.64; RMI TCP Connectio(2)-192.168.1.64, RMI TCP Accept-0; DestroyJavaVM; Attach Listener; Signal Dispatcher

Comment: Hello, how did you solve this issue.